# Not working validation input in application

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I have problem width validation input "password" and "login" in my application. I tests it on Google Chrome and Android device. I don't know why is not working. 
Help me. 
Thanks

It is not working code:

```
<input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="login" autofocus="" required="required"/>
<input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include those code inside form tag like this

```
<form>
 <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="login" autofocus="" required="required"/>
<input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required"/>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```